# What is the url for Facebook authentication with WebAuthenticationCoreManager

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-10, windows-identity

I have this code for Facebook authentication

```
var scopes = "email user_birthday user_events user_friends user_about_me";
WebAccountProvider facebookAccountProvider = 
      await WebAuthenticationCoreManager
            .FindAccountProviderAsync("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");
WebTokenRequest webTokenRequest = new WebTokenRequest(facebookAccountProvider, scopes);
```

WebAuthenticationCoreManager does not like Facebook OAuth endpoint https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth and sets my facebookAccountProvider to null.
Does anyone know how I can get FindAccountProviderAsync working with Facebook?

Comment: Please have a look on [Manually build a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2)

Comment: That's where I got "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" from. it does not work with this new Windows 10 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync()` finds account providers that have been registered with Windows. This means (say) the Facebook app would need to support it (which it doesn't). At the moment it's only useful for Microsoft accounts and organizational accounts (Office 365/Azure AD).

If you want to use Facebook's OAuth 2.0 implementation directly you can use [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) instead (there are examples on that page).